# How to check is website visitor fan of my facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

can someone help me please how to check is visitor on my website fan of my facebook page,thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using the graph API. Make a request to https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?fields=id&access_token=....
You will recieve a JSON object back that looks like this:

```
{ "data": [
  {
     "id": "167719689909536",
     "created_time": "2010-10-12T17:52:07+0000"
  },
  {
     "id": "48543634386",
     "created_time": "2010-10-08T15:51:56+0000"
  },
  {
     "id": "116444998394332",
     "created_time": "2010-10-07T03:50:46+0000"
  },
  {
     "id": "165752823438719",
     "created_time": "2010-10-07T01:50:51+0000"
  }
```

]
}

From this you can just iterate through the likes until you find if the like you are looking for exists. If you don't know the id of your Url you can simply go to http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.mydomain.com/myurl and you will be given a JSON result that contains the ID of your page.

Comment: Thank you Nathan Totten,I will try this.

Comment: Did this work out for you? If so please consider marking it as the answer.